# R Correction of curves and scale

Tags: r, plot, curve

I have my code that generates curves for me:

```
C=c(0,0.3,1.5,3.5,19.5)
v1=c(0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.22, 0.84) 
v2=c(0.10, 0.74, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00)
mlist_procent = c(0.9852836, 0.7762951, 0.3899078, 0.2281043, 0.0602995)


plot_c <-plot(C, mlist_procent, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = range(mlist_procent),
              col = "black",  xlab = "C", ylab = "means")

par(new=TRUE)
plot_c4 <-plot(C, v1, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = range(mlist_procent),
               col = "blue", xlab = "C", ylab = "means")
par(new=TRUE)
plot_c5 <-plot(C, v2, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = range(mlist_procent),
               col = "red", xlab = "C", ylab = "means")
```

I want to get a plot where the blue and red curves are inverse and there is only one scale on the y-axis.

I try :

```
plot_c <- plot(C, mlist_procent, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = range(mlist_procent),
               col = "black", xlab = "C", ylab = "means", ann = FALSE)
par(new = TRUE)
plot_c4 <- plot(C, v1, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = rev(range(mlist_procent)),
                col = "blue", xlab = "C", ylab = "means", ann = FALSE)
par(new = TRUE)
plot_c5 <- plot(C, v2, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = rev(range(mlist_procent)),
                col = "red", xlab = "C", ylab = "means", ann = FALSE)
```

I get more scales on the y-axis and also fewer points for the blue curve I need all curves to have 5 points how change it for the blue curve? Do I need to somehow normalize the data before plotting? I don't know how to fix my plot  so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use one plot statement and a custom ylim values if I follow what you are after

This:

```
plot_c <-plot(C, mlist_procent, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = c(0,1.1),
              col = "black",  xlab = "C", ylab = "means")
lines(C,v1,col="blue")
points(C,v1,col="blue",pch=19)
lines(C,v2,col="red")
points(C,v2,col="red",pch=19)
```

To invert the red and blue curves you can just do:

```
plot_c <-plot(C, mlist_procent, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = c(0,1.1),
              col = "black",  xlab = "C", ylab = "means")
lines(C,1-v1,col="blue")
points(C,1-v1,col="blue",pch=19)
lines(C,1-v2,col="red")
points(C,1-v2,col="red",pch=19)
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you 
DashdotdotDashdotdot very much for the answer, but I also need the red and blue curves to be revers to be  in the same direction as the black curve like in my second code snippet

Comment: I added a second code block to show how to do this.

Comment: One more thing if possible. i want to make sure i understand correctly if for example instead of 1-v1 i give 1+v1 and so on i will get all curves ascending (up)?

Comment: By graphing 1+v1 you are just adding 1 to v1, and so on, if v1 is c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75) you will graph c(1.25, 1.5, 1.75).  In my code, it is just graph three sets of points on the same scale and graph whatever the points are (after the transformation).

Comment: Thank you again.  means that I don't quite understand the inversion of the curves. What then would I have to do to reverse the black curve, for example ( it to rise)?

Comment: plot_c <-plot(C,1- mlist_procent, type = "b", pch = 19, ylim = c(0,1.1),
              col = "black",  xlab = "C", ylab = "means") (will make it start close to 0 and increase to become close to 1.)